# Publish/Unpublish Adobe AEM page from Java

Tags: java, aem

We have background process that automatically creates AEM pages as well as deletes old AEM pages. For pages to appear/disappear on the published site, they need to be activated (Published) / deactivated (Unpublished).

However, after searching from Google, I am not able to find AEM Java API that can publish/unpublish pages automatically.

Where can I find information on how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

what you are looking for is the [Replicator](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Replicator.html) api. [ReplicationActionType](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/ReplicationActionType.html) decides if you want to activate or deactivate.

```
replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE,path);
replicator.replicate(session,ReplicationActionType.DEACTIVATE,path);
```

You can obtain Replicator instance using the @Reference annotation inside your OSGI service.

```
@Reference
Replicator replicator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about running the same background process on the publisher instead of activating/deactivating the pages?
I mean in case for some reasons your process fails during activation/deactivation you need to handle it and make sure that your publishers are still in a consistent state.

Answer (score -1):

https://aem.redquark.org/2018/10/day-19-replication-api-in-action.html

Please refer this reference looks to be good and moreover if you want to deactivate you can use

```
replicator.replicate(session, ReplicationActionType.DEACTIVATE, path);
            log.info("Replicated:---- {}", path);
```